# FATAL : No Bootable medium found! System halted

Tags: virtualbox, iso, backtrack

I just got a .iso of the linux distro Backtrack 5 R2. I set it up, using virtual box, and set it up to run using the .iso, and hard drive as a .vdi. Here's the setup:

**System:** Base Memory: 1500 MB Boot Order: CD/DVD-ROM, Hard Disk Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging

**Storage:** IDE Controller IDE Primary Master (CD/DVD): BT5R2-KDE-64.iso (2.62 GB)

SATA Controller SATA Port 0: Backtrack 5 R2.vdi (Normal, 8.00 GB)

Why would I be getting this error? Everything looks fine to me. And also, I'm running virtual box in a Windows 7 64bit OS.

Comment: Did you check the VBox.log? Posting it might help a bit. Press Crtl+L in VirtualBox when the BackTrack entry is selected or go look for it somewhere around here: /home/$USER/.VirtualBox/Machines/$YOURMACHINE/Logs

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem before, and I troubleshooted as follows:

1. I checked if my ISO image was mounted in VirtualBox and it was.
2. I checked if my ISO image was corrupted and indeed it was.
3. I fixed the ISO image and tried again, and it worked like a charm.

SHA1 and MD5 checksums are normally published alongside ISO images to check against after you download.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following under [VirtualMachine] > Settings:

1. [System] > Boot order : Is CD/DVD drive checked and first on the list?
2. [Storage] > CD/DVD Drive : Is the image mounted and chackbox 'Live CD/DVD' checked?

BTW, why are you using SATA for your virtual disk port?
(I've got a IDE controller, BT VDI disk as prim master and DVD drive as sec master under it, host Win7 x64 Ult = works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a IDE controller instead of SATA.

Comment: Is this something you know from experience (if so, please say so in your answer), or is it a random stab at troubleshooting? If the latter, please realize that the question was asked in 2012, and the user asking hasn't been back to the site since then...

Comment: This is a valid answer. Even today Virtualbox 5.0.24 fails to boot from a ISO image on a SATA controller *if the first controller is IDE*. Either make the first controller SATA and the second IDE. Or remove the IDE controller completely if you don't need it.